# Can we request the user to provide the capsule with location and other permissions again?

Tags: bixby

Currently when the user runs a capsule he is asked to share location permissions during the setup phase. Is it possible to request for these permissions again, based on specific queries, to which the user can respond with a 'yes' or 'no'? Eg. 'What is my nearest xyz', to find the nearest xyz we need the users location.

[User Permission Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wer5r.png)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to re-prompt the user for permissions at this time. You can however check if the permissions were granted, and use dialog to ask the user to turn on the permissions themselves.